# c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file:

Tags: node.js

### Background

I am trying to code a Discord-Bot, for which I wanted to use "Discord.js". It has to be installed with/by node.js (I think :D).

I never used node.js, so I read the Instructions: (something like) just install node, type in this and that and have fun...

But (at first) nothing worked and I slowly fixed all the problems by hardcore googling.

### Problem

But there is one thing I couldn't find a good answer to, so now i'm here...
When I build:

> c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file:
>   '..\src\binding.cc': No such file or directory
>   [C:\Users\Ossi\Desktop\Desktop\Programme\Neuer
>   Ordner\Bot\build\binding.vcxproj]

(btw i'm a total noob in everything that doesn't have Java in it's name... [and even there I am really not the best])

### Question

How can I fix my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You get that error message when you do... what?

Comment: `\Desktop\Desktop` do you have such folder structure ?

Comment: It sounds dumb, but i have it

Comment: Some people said I have to edit the binding.vcxproj, but I don't know, how to do it

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because the program is searching for a folder that does not exist.

You can copy and paste the path give in the error into Windows Explorer, and see if it finds something !

`C:\Users\Ossi\Desktop\Desktop\Programme\Neuer Ordner\Bot\build\`

I believe you wont find anything!

Create the missing folder or fix the path to it and it should be fixed!

Comment: I found it :( It exists

Comment: You have a folder Desktop inside another fodder called desktop?

Comment: If so,try checking if you have permissions to read and write from it!

Comment: Yes, and I am in admin mode

Comment: It's dumb, I know, but I didn't know how I should name it... :D